# How to use standard php package in Laravel? I try to import it but it can't be found?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I installed this Json Verification package:

https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

It's just a PHP package it installs into vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema. 
It's composer.json is located here if look into it is needed: https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema/blob/master/composer.json

I need to access it in my Code so I tried this in my Controller:

```
use JsonSchema\Validator;
```

when I do this inside a method:

```
$validator = new JsonSchema\Validator;
```

I get this error:

```
 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'App\Commands\JsonSchema\Validator' not found
```

Package has been installed with composer and is in the vendor folder.

How do I access it so that I can run some code that it shows on its GitHub page:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));

// Validate
$validator = new JsonSchema\Validator;
$validator->validate($data, (object)['$ref' => 'file://' . realpath('schema.json')]);

if ($validator->isValid()) {
    echo "The supplied JSON validates against the schema.\n";
} else {
    echo "JSON does not validate. Violations:\n";
    foreach ($validator->getErrors() as $error) {
        echo sprintf("[%s] %s\n", $error['property'], $error['message']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by doing this:

```
use JsonSchema\Validator as JsonValidator;
```

and in the method:

```
$validator = new JsonValidator;
```

Comment: You could use also `new \JsonSchema\Validator();`.